Eclipse doesn't remember customisations across workspaces
I disliked the default font families and sizes for the different components in the Eclipse IDE, so I changed everything up a long time ago.
For the first time today, I opened Eclipse using another workspace directory because I started working on different types of projects and thought it would be advantageous to use different directories.
My problem is that when I change the Eclipse workspace, the configurations for the font family and size don't follow. If I go back to my default workspace, however, the settings are restored, meaning that they are stored in that directory.
How do I make Eclipse's settings generalised, if possible? If not possible, what is a workaround? Am I required to copy files across workspaces every time I generate a new workspace?
Note. I specifically mentioned the fonts because they are what took me the most time to set up to my liking in the past. However, having the windows not dock to my liking by default is also an annoyance, although I can relatively quickly fix that by hand.
Also, I absolutely do not want the build configurations and all that stuff to follow through my different workspaces. The point of setting up multiple working directories was to unclutter my environment.
======= Edit ========
I forgot to mention that I know about the export/import feature for preferences and perspectives in Eclipse. The reason I posted the above question is because I don't want to have to do this manually every time.
